# Troubles with Hibernate Dialect and XAMPP (MySQL-MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, xampp, mariadb

I want to connect my Java application to a MySQL database. For this I use the MySQL DB, which comes with XAMPP. Furthermore I use Hibernate. I have already successfully persisted my application via PostgreSQL, but MySQL causes problems because I haven't found the right dialect, although I have already tried out a lot of different dialects.

> Hibernate: create table keytype (id bigint not null, primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'key (id bigint not null, idType varchar(255), local bit not null, type varchar(2' at line 1

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
```

```
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.21'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.4.15.Final'
compile group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence', version: '2.2.1'
```

**DB**

```
DBMS: MySQL (ver. 5.5.5-10.4.11-MariaDB)
Case sensitivity: plain=lower, delimited=lower
Driver: MySQL Connector/J (ver. mysql-connector-java-8.0.21 (Revision: 33f65445a1bcc544eb0120491926484da168f199), JDBC4.2)
Effective version: MariaDB (ver. 10.4.11)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that if you say that you have tried many dialects, you will have tried

- `org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect`
- `org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect`

so most likely the problem is with the connector. You can try to use version 5.1

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

Comment: I have tried both dialects, but neither of them works. I have also tried them again, unfortunately without success. I set the Conncetor to version 5.1 and tried both Mysql and Mariadb dialects, unfortunately it still doesn't work.